# How to change the default "Bing" search engine for "New tab" in the Chromium Edge Browser to something else?

Tags: browser, chromium, microsoft-edge

As the title already explains, I want to change the default search engine from Bing to something else. This is **not** the same setting as for the search bar!

[image: Because Microsoft]

**EDIT:**

Without proprietary third-party software (extensions)!

Comment: Currently you can't. If you want to use another search engine, you must use the address bar (after changing the search engine in the settings).

Comment: Make new tap open in google.com ?